# How do I specify the 3D Cartesian coordinates of each vertex in a plane?

Tags: coordinates

I have a specific system with a given origin. I want to make a plane with 3 vertices where each vertex has a specific position in 3D space relative to the global origin that I want to specify explicitly. I know that you can move vertices in each direction with your cursor but I want to set it in place the same way you specify the position of a UV sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing it by hand, in Edit (Vertex) mode when a single vertex is selected, you can read/write its coordinates in the <kbd>N</kbd> Properties Region, 'Item' tab.

[image]

You have the option of seeing them in World or Object space.